# How to detach all objects from Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate

From time to time I need to clean Hibernate session.

How to prevent LazyInitializationException with obects that are attached to this session?

I am searching for something like session.detachAllObjects().
and then invoke session.clear()

After this I suppose these objects will be retrieved from DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`session.clear()` detaches all objects.

`LazyInitializationException` usually means that the entities are detached from a session, or a session is closed. If you want to avoid it, attach an object to a session (using `session.merge(..)`), or don't close it (using [`OpenSessionInView`](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView))

Comment: Is there a way to detach an object and when I try to navigate a lazy child collection i should get NullPointerException instead of LazyInitializationException?

Comment: So for exposing Web Service we can't use Hibernate at all? Because if I detach the Entity it will throw LIE, if it is attached to Session it will pull all the Object graph which is not desirable.

Comment: You can use hibernate, you'll have to either use a DTO in which you transfer all the state from the entity (and decide whether to initialize or not the collections), or don't use lazy collections at all (http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=645)

Comment: Avoiding lazyloading won't work for me. Without all these hacking it seems good to go with SpringJDBC or MyBatis.

Comment: it will work for you if your data model is mapped properly ;)